how to automatically switch the kafka client to another cluster without restart
I learnning kafka active/standy cluster , by read the cloudera article of  Connection to the cluster with configured DNS aliases，i have some questions.
important part of above link article: If the client has discovered a cluster and is actively using it, and the cluster suddenly stops, the client tries to connect to the bootstrap servers it got from the DNS server before the bootstrap phase. So it does not automatically ask the DNS server for new bootstrap servers and does not fail over to the other cluster, even if the DNS records have already been changed.
my questions:  has any solution can automatically switch kafka client reconnect the standy cluster without restart kafka client ?
I used the dnsmasq service to simulate a disaster recovery scenario, and I found that the Kafka client could not automatically switch the connected standy cluster unless I manually restarted the kafka client

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have attempted the same approach, and even when forcibly triggering a rebalance (by creating a fake consumer), I observed that each client directly interacts with the Coordinator using the cached metadata without querying the bootstrap server again.
Therefore, the bootstrap server information is not re-queried, and the only way to force this is by restarting the client.
The metadata.max.age.ms parameter also results in metadata being requested from the Coordinator, not from the DNS set in the bootstrap server.
In conclusion, it seems that outside of restarting the client, there is currently no method to force the client to re-query the bootstrap server. the official Kafka client does not provide this functionality. It seems necessary to develop a separate extension to enable it.
